# proof that SO(3) is simple

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Im following the book "Naive Lie theory" by Stillwell.
and on section 2.3 there's a proof explaining why $G=SO(3)$ is simple, i.e. dosn't have any non trivial normal subgroup except itself.
I cant seem to understand the last part of the proof:

[image]

[image]

meaning the part starting from: 
"As P varies continuously over some interval...."
why does it follow that theta takes some value of the form $\frac{m\cdot\pi}{n}$ where $m$ is odd?
I cant seem to understand why that is so trivial?
and from that part until the end(all the second page) I cant understand..
can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that for small angles, the "movement" is bicontinuous, so the range of values of $\theta$ when varying $P$ along an open set in the great circle $PQ$ is an open set. The rationals multiples of $\pi$ are dense in the reals, so in this open set, we can pick a rational multiple of $\pi$ as $\theta$.

Generally, in any nonempty open set in we can pick a rational multiple of some number $\beta$.